# GetActiveOleObject - Exception: Operation Unavailable

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I'm have trouble with my `Inno Setup`, it gives me the exception `Operation Unavailable`.

I even tried using the example code `CodeAutomation.iss` provided by `Inno Setup` and it still is giving me the same error. How do I get `GetActiveOleObject` to work? Am I missing something?

This is the code in the `Inno Setup` example:

```
{--- Word ---}

procedure WordButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Word: Variant;
begin
  if MsgBox('Setup will now check whether Microsoft Word is running. Do you want to continue?', mbInformation, mb_YesNo) = idNo then
    Exit;

  { Try to get an active Word COM Automation object }

  try
    //This is where the error occurs.
    Word := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application'); 
  except
  end;

  if VarIsEmpty(Word) then
    MsgBox('Microsoft Word is not running.', mbInformation, mb_Ok)
  else
    MsgBox('Microsoft Word is running.', mbInformation, mb_Ok)
end;
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following newsgroup postings:

http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg71386.html

http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg71387.html

This is by design and only happens when run through the IDE. Are you getting the error when running a compiled setup?  I just tried the code from CodeAutomation.iss on a Win7 SP1 x64 machine and it worked correctly.

Comment: I think the by design bit relates to the popping up of exceptions, not why you get an "operation not available" exception. Note that in the debugger config of Delphi you can configure for which exceptions the program is halted.